# What are the equivalents of Java <? extends Foo> and <? super Foo> in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I've read a lot of posts but still can't find the right equivalents of Java `<? extends Foo>` and `<? super Foo>` in TypeScript. Can anyone give exact answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Even though you may be using Java as a point of comparison, your question is really about [tag:typescript], and so tagging [tag:java] in your question is not helpful to you.

Comment: I believe what you're looking for is covariance / contravariance type annotations, which is currently [just a proposal for TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10717).